# CodeIgniter $this->input->get_post() empty Views to Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controllers

This is my Code :

Views :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/rbts/get_songs">
        <div class="form-group">
             <!-------------------------------------------------------- TOP Songs-------------------------------------------------------------->
                 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Top 1</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_1" id="drptop_1" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 1;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select>

                   </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Top 2</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_2" id="drptop_2" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 2;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>        
                    </select>
                   </div> <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Top 3</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_3" id="drptop_3" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 3;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>    
                    </select>
                   </div> <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Top 4</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_4" id="drptop_4" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 4;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>        
                    </select>
                   </div> <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Top 5</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_5" id="drptop_5" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 5;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>        
                    </select>
                   </div>
                   <br><br>
        <!-------------------------------------------------------- New Songs-------------------------------------------------------------->
        <hr height="5px" width="100%">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New 1</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_6" id="drptop_6" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 6;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>        
                    </select>
                   </div> <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New 2</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_7" id="drptop_7" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 7;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>                
                    </select>
                   </div> <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New 3</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_8" id="drptop_8" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 8;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>                    
                    </select>
                   </div> <br><br>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New 4</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_9" id="drptop_9" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 9;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{
                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>                
                    </select>
                   </div>
                   <br><br>
                     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">New 5</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select name="drptop_10" id="drptop_10" class="form-control m-b">
                    <?php       
                        $n = 10;
                        foreach($songs as $song){
                            if($song['id']==$n){
                    ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else if($song['id']==null){
                    ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo "--------" ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }
                            else{

                    ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $song['rbt_id']; ?>"><?php echo $song['title']; ?></option>
                    <?php
                            }

                        }



                    ?>  


                    </select>
                   </div>
                   <br><br>
                 </div>
                </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/rbts/get_songs/" class="btn btn-default">Save</a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
         </div>
    </form>
```

controllers :

```
public function get_songs(){


        $top1=$this->input->get_post('drptop1');
        $top2=$this->input->get_post('drptop2');
        $top3=$this->input->get_post('drptop3');
        $top4=$this->input->get_post('drptop4');
        $top5=$this->input->get_post('drptop5');
        $new1=$this->input->get_post('drptop6');
        $new2=$this->input->get_post('drptop7');
        $new3=$this->input->get_post('drptop8');
        $new4=$this->input->get_post('drptop9');
        $new5=$this->input->get_post('drptop10');


        die(var_dump($top1));

    //$this ->rbt->update_all_songs($top1,$top2,$top3,$top4,$top5,$new1,$new2,$new3,$new4,$new5);


}
```

And after that it always says `bool(false). =.=`

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting `bool(false)` because there is no value in $top1.

Secondly, the input name in the form is differnt from the variable name you are using to fetch the value.

```
Example:
<select name="drptop_1" id="drptop_1" class="form-control m-b"></select>
AND    
$top1=$this->input->get_post('drptop1');
```

Try, using same input name `name="drptop_1"` and php variable name `get_post('drptop1')`
Hope this is helpful.